# Programmatically inserting an image in an Infopath form

Tags: infopath

I create Infopath forms programmatically and one of the items I want to include now is pictures.

Note: I have created list items programmatically with client object model with pictures in it using the hyperlink field and showing it like a picture but I don't see this option in Infopath, instead I see the picture component but it doesn't seems to accept urls or streams.

Note2: the images I want to use are from a picture library in the same SharePoint site.

How can be achieved?

Comment: How are you creating the forms programmatically? What method? Have you tried a byte array, or a base64 encoded string?

Comment: I use client object model from an asp .net page, I load the xml, I modify it and then savebinary to the original file.

Comment: That's pretty clever. I don't know about the Picture component in InfoPath, but if it's anything like the Attachment component, the image and it's filename are combined and Base64'd, and Microsoft has code to work with them: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2517906

Comment: I've seen the link you send, the problem is that it works inside Infopath, if I try to copy that code to ASP .NET it doesn't found classes like XmlNamespaceManager for example, I need the code to do it in client object model in asp .net.

Comment: This code works outside InfoPath fine, I've used it. You just need to add the missing references to your ASP.NET project. `XmlNamespaceManager` is within System.Xml.dll, for example.

Comment: excuse me, I'm a newbie.

Comment: This MSDN article should help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/wkze6zky.aspx - look for System.Xml.dll when adding the reference,  then the XmlNamespaceManager shoudl resolve in the above sample code.

Comment: The problem was that all the code I found before this referenced NameSpaceManager (that is not in XML.dll), and only worked inside Infopath so when I saw this code I thought that it was not going to work.thanks.